# C# и обобщенная (generic) лямбда

Tags: c#

Есть ли в c# возможность создать обобщенную лямбду, например

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Fun(x => x * x, x => x + x, 3));

    Func<Func<int, int>, Func<int, int>, int, int> fun = (a, b, x) => a(b(x));

    Console.WriteLine(fun(x => x * x, x => x + x, 3));
}
static T Fun<T>(Func<T, T> a, Func<T, T> b,T x)
{
    return a(b(x));
}
```

Вот есть функция `Fun`, и она обобщенная, но есть ли возможность то же провернуть с лямбдой, например один раз я хочу вызвать лямбду `fun` с типом `int`, а другой раз с типом `double`

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, определять собственные обобщенные параметры лямбды не могут.